# How to change below procedure to (update & insert) instead of (delete &insert) in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to update the record if already exists based on where condition or else insert. I have written query with delete and insert I am facing difficulty into converting into update and insert.

PS: I have tried using `SQL%ROWCOUNT` but I think i missed somewhere in syntax.
Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the proc i am using

```
Create Or Replace Procedure sal_proc(Empid Varchar2,Fmdt Date,bp Number)
As
Begin
--delete
delete from Emp_Sal
Where Empid = Empid
And   Fmdt = Fmdt;
--insert
Insert Into Emp_Sal(empid,fmdt,Basicpay) Values (empid,fmdt,Bp);
End;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a procedure; you can use [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/MERGE.htm#SQLRF01606) to update or insert a row at the same time:

```
merge into Emp_Sal e
using ( 
        /* your values to insert/update */ 
        select 2 as Empid, 'c' as Fmdt, 100 as Bp from dual
      ) x
on ( e.Empid = x.Empid And e.Fmdt = x.Fmdt)
when matched
    then  /* if a record exists, update */
       update set Basicpay = Bp
when not matched
    then /* it the record does not exist, insert */
    insert values (x.empid, x.fmdt, x.Bp)
```

Of course you can use this inside a procedure to handle your input parameters or do whatever you may need to do in your procedure:

```
Create Or Replace Procedure sal_proc(Empid Varchar2,Fmdt Date,bp Number)
As
Begin
    merge into Emp_Sal e
    using ( 
            /* your values to insert/update */ 
            select Empid as Empid, Fmdt as Fmdt, bp as Bp from dual
          ) x
    on ( e.Empid = x.Empid And e.Fmdt = x.Fmdt)
    when matched
        then  /* if a record exists, update */
           update set Basicpay = Bp
    when not matched
        then /* it the record does not exist, insert */
        insert (empid,fmdt,Basicpay) values (x.empid, x.fmdt, x.Bp);
End;
```

An hint: use parameter names different fron column names to avoid confusion; a good practice could be use parameter names like `p_XXX`; just an example of how dangerous this can be:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure checkPar(n in number) is
  2      c number;
  3  begin
  4      select count(1)
  5      into c
  6      from checkTab
  7      where n = n;
  8      --
  9      dbms_output.put_line(c);
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> select * from checkTab;

         N
----------
         1
         2
         3

SQL> exec checkPar(1);
3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec checkPar(999);
3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I need procedure because i am calling this procedure from PHP

Comment: You can simply use this in the procedure, as just shown.

Comment: Ok. I am trying to execute. Please give me a moment i will be back with response. Thanks for the help

Comment: Why am i getting Error as `ORA-00947:not enough values`

Comment: Your table should have more than 3 columns; just edited

Comment: It worked thanks the error was because of one missing column value actually there were 14 more columns so i missed one col.

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient way but should work if huge data is not present in tables

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sal_proc (E_Empid VARCHAR2, F_Fmdt DATE, b_bp NUMBER)
    AS
    var number;
    BEGIN

      Begin 
      --Checking if record exists
       select 1
       into var 
       from Emp_Sal
       Where Empid = E_Empid
       And   Fmdt = F_Fmdt;

      exception
        when no_data_found then
          var:= 0;
       End;

        if var <> 1  then   
       --insert
        INSERT INTO Emp_Sal (empid, fmdt, Basicpay)    
            VALUES (e_empid, f_fmdt, b_Bp);
        else

        update Emp_Sal
        set col ....<>;

        end if;

    END;
```

Comment: I believe this does not work: the SELECT query will match the columns whit themselves and not with the parameters.

Comment: I guess you didnot understood my logic..My SELECT will return 1 when table has the record. So in that case my `IF ELSE` block will work. Its same as what you mentioned like `Merge`. I guess you must not downvote if you believe something doesnot work :-)

Comment: See the example in my question. Your select will give too_many_rows if there are many records in the table, or no_data_found if there are no records.

Comment: I guess that's again your assumption that the table can have many rows for same `emp_id` and `fmdt.`. In that case it would fail. But my assumption is 1 record for the input.

Comment: emp_id and fmdt have are unique combinations there will be one record only.

Comment: ok, so this will only give  no_data_found if the record does not exist

Comment: Am checking `var`..it would go to else loop..Am not catching any exception. I again reiterate `must not downvote if you believe something doesnot work` on your assumptions.

Comment: No, the first query will give no_data_found if the record does not exist or the table is empty. Please try your code before posting it.